# Find highest number from a list (given in a txt file) using import (function) in python

Tags: python, list, file

I am a beginner and trying to solve a problem.
**- Find the highest number in a list (without using max() function) with below instructions**

1. create a text file which has a list
2. create a function to identify highest value in a list
3. in a separate program, read the text file created in step# 1 and using function from step #2 above find the highest value in the list given in text file

**Solution Tried**:

1. I created a text file with a list in a folder  [23, -1, 5, 4]
2. created a function (funcion_list.py) to find the highest value in list

```
def max_item(list):
    maximum = 0
    for value in list:
        if value > maximum:
            maximum = value
    return maximum
```

3. in my playground.py program, I imported the function max_item(list), read the list from the text file and passed it as an argument in the function to find the highest number in the list

```
from function_list import max_item

new_list = []

with open("file1.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip("\n"))        
        new_list.append((line))
        
print(max_item(new_list))
```

Output:
**I am able to read the appended file but I am getting below error instead of getting highest value printed.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playground.py", line 13, in <module>  
    print(max_item(new_list))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "function_list.py", line 4, in max_item
    if value > maximum:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Could you please help in pointing what wrong am I doing?

Comment: You forgot to convert the input line into an integer.Try " new_list.append( int(line))"

Comment: `maximum = 0` is a bug if negative numbers are possible in the list. Initializing `maximum` like that would give the wrong result for `[-3,-2,-1]`

Comment: You store strings in your list `new_list`, but you want integer values. Change `new_list.append((line))` to `new_list.append(int(line))`. Additionally: Don't call your own variable `list` because you overwrite Pythons built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: Does your file contain the brackets and commas to denote the list, or is it just one number per line? If it's the former, parse it using `json.load`. if it's the latter, take the advice given to you above

Answer (score 2):

`open` will read everything as a string. You need to convert it to an `int` before adding it to the list.

Change this line
`new_list.append((line))`
to
`new_list.append((int(line)))`